# jquery not updating handlebars partial view correctly when submitting a form (express, node.js)

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using Node.JS with Express and Handlebars. I was having trouble just updating a particular div as well as sending data.

I'll ask the question from the 10' level first because maybe the details are unnecessary to answer. When I use `href='blah'` and set up a jquery function then Express does the right thing and just updates the div without updating the whole page.

When I use the same code on a `<form method="post" ....` however, it instead drops my layout, doesn't go to the jquery call, but does render the entire handlebars page that I routed to via Express.

Why are these different and what should I be doing instead?

**If that wasn't clear, then here is code:**

Inside my view directory I have: index.handlebars, view1.handlebars, temp.handlebars.

Inside view1.handlebars, I have a `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="/update_this" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-id="{{data.uniqueId}}">
```

and a `div`:

```
<div id="sectional">
    {{> partial}}
</div>
```

And when someone clicks the `button`, I want to update the sectional `div`. So I use jquery like so:

```
$('#btn-here').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id_num = $(this).data('id'); //id_num is correct

    $.get("/temp/" + id_num, function(res) {
       var updated_html = res;
       $('#sectional').html(updated_html);
   });
});
```

I allow the jquery to find the temp.handlebars file via:

```
router.get('/temp/:id', view1.showstuff);
```

And inside the view1.showstuff function:

```
showstuff: function(req, res) {
            res.locals.model = model;
            res.render('temp/' + id, {layout: false});
        };
```

This renders the whole page and loses even the layout.handlebars file.

As stated, if I instead have a button with an `href=...` then the layout stays and everything renders perfectly. But something about the fact that I am doing a `post` request instead of a `get` causes the issue.

Comment: It loses the layouts because of `{layout: false}`

Comment: `{layout: false}` means don't update the layout. It doesn't mean turn it off. You use the setting when you are just updating one section of a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well jquery can load html directly into an element using `$(<someElement>).load`. Here's the docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/ Basically, by pointing to a route coming from your node server that sends html, `.load` will replace the current html with the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the jquery is not being called at all. I have this working for 'get', but when I change the 'get' to a 'post' it breaks. Do you see a specific error?